# Configuration of assertion valid to datetime

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

I'm implementing NemLog-in3 / OIOSAML 3 authentication in my .NET Core web application. With great success so far. I only have this one question about the security token validation, when getting the assertion from the IdP, after authentication.

When i get the assertion from the IdP, it has a SecurityToken in the response, with a validFrom and a validTo Datetime. The difference is +1 hour, but in the OIOSAML3 test documentation, it says to "invalidate" the assertion and that your SP should reject the user from logging in after 5 minutes.

Do you know if it's possible to configure the securityToken valid period (set it to 5 minutes), perhaps when initiating the SAML authentication? I know i could just check the validTo and add 5 minutes to it, but i'd rather have it working dynamically, with the validTo property, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Conditions` elements `NotBefore` and `NotOnOrAfter` is valid for an hour, which is correct. The 5 minutes login restriction should have been in the `SubjectConfirmation` element `NotOnOrAfter`. It looks like an error in NemLog-in3?

NemLog-in3 SAML 2.0 authn response:

```
<Subject>
    <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" SPNameQualifier="https://saml.itfoxtecidentitysaml2-public-dev.sample">
        https://data.gov.dk/model/core/eid/professional/uuid/8e190635-4a9c-4748-91ed-24895f809647
    </NameID>
    <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_29a72131-ab30-4429-b083-b18db2d6160e" NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-08T13:22:32.062Z" Recipient="https://localhost:44310/Auth/AssertionConsumerService"/>
        </SubjectConfirmation>
    </Subject>
    <Conditions NotBefore="2021-09-08T12:22:31.843Z" NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-08T13:22:31.843Z">
    <AudienceRestriction>
        <Audience>
            https://saml.itfoxtecidentitysaml2-public-dev.sample
        </Audience>
    </AudienceRestriction>
</Conditions>
```

Comment: I based our solution on your example project TestWebAppCoreNemlogin3Sp, and when i look in the response i get in the assertion endpoint, i can't find the subjectConfirmation on the object? Am i looking for it in the wrong place?

Comment: I'm validading the SubjectConfirmation NotOnOrAfter https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnResponse.cs#L269. But there is not a property to easily access the SubjectConfirmation. You can access the element the same way as in the ValidateAssertionExpiration method.

Comment: Okay, so your are telling me that it's built into the functionality from your NuGet package? If i use  your "ReadSamlResponse" method to read the response

Comment: It is validated by calling the Unbind method, which will throw an exception if the time is invalid. The ReadSamlResponse method only read the response.

Comment: Alright, i figured it out. Also, i do think there's a bug in the assertion, since the datetime passed to my tokencache is actually just approx DateTime.UtcNow, so all entried just expires immediately